# ¿Como guardar usando el tipo de dato rowtype en PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
declare

begin
   
l_header tabla1%rowtype;

l_header.num_id := 1;

insert into tabla1 values l_header;

end;
```

Pero me manda el siguiente error :

```
[Error] Execution (4: 10): ORA-06550: line 4, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " tabla1" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for " tabla1" to continue
```

¿Cual será la manera idioma de emplear ese tipo de dato?

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que el rowtype lo debes declarar en la seccion DECLARE, no en el cuerpo del bloque, por otra parte, seguro que existe el objeto con nombre tabla1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PL/SQL la declaración de variables debe ir en la sección `declare` de un bloque.

En ese y muchos otros *detalles* PL/SQL es parecido al lenguaje [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal), del cual deriva. La sección `declare` sería equivalente a la sección `var` de un bloque en pascal.

Así, la estructura de tu código debiera lucir algo como:

```
declare
  l_header tabla1%rowtype;
begin
  l_header.num_id := 1;
  insert into tabla1 values l_header;
end;
```

Además de mover de lugar la declaración, he eliminado las líneas en blanco y he añadido indentación, que no es requerida por la computadora, pero si que ayuda a hacer más legible el código para los humanos.